# Reactive forms multiple checkboxes select all not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm new to Reactive Forms in Angular. I have multiple checkbox arrays in my form. When user clicks 'Select All' button I need to select all checkboxes. In my example I want to check all age list values. when user clicks 'Deselect All' I want to deselect all. I tried , but it's not working.

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <p>Language</p>
    <div *ngFor="let data of languages let i = index">
        <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(data.name, $event.target.checked)"> {{data.name}}<br>
    </div>

<p>Age List</p>
  <button (click)="checkAll()">Check all</button>
    <button (click)="deselectAll()">Deselect all</button>
  <div *ngFor="let data of ages let j = index">
        <input type="checkbox" (change)="onAgeChange(data.name, $event.target.checked)"> {{data.name}}<br>
    </div>
</form>

<pre>Form values: {{myForm.value | json}}</pre>
```

App Component

```
  ages = [{ ageID: 100 ,name: "0 -10 years" }, {ageID: 200 ,name: "10 -20 years" }, {ageID: 300 ,name: "30 -40 years" }, { ageID: 400 ,name: "40 -50 years"  }]
  languages = [{ langID: 1 ,name: "English" }, {langID: 2 ,name: "Tamil" }, {langID: 3 ,name: "Hindi" }, { langID: 4 ,name: "French"  }]


  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      userage: this.fb.array([]),
      userlanguage: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  onChange(language: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const languageFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.userlanguage;

    if (isChecked) {
      languageFormArray.push(new FormControl(language));
    } else {
      let index = languageFormArray .controls.findIndex(x => x.value == language)
      languageFormArray .removeAt(index);
    }
  }

  onAgeChange(age : string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const ageFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.userage;

    if (isChecked) {
      ageFormArray.push(new FormControl(age));

    } else {
      let index = ageFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == age)
      ageFormArray.removeAt(index);
    }
  }


  checkAll(){
    const languageFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.userlanguage;
    //console.log(this.myForm.controls['userage'])
 this.myForm.controls['userage'].setValue(
        this.myForm.controls['userage'].value
            .map(value => true)
    );
  }
```

This is what I tried so far
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-butm3h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Appreciate if anyone can give me a support.

Comment: A link to code isn’t as useful as putting the actual code in the question.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your question has no code. “Why isn’t this code working?” requires code. I’m not going to follow a link to code to try to sort out what might be wrong. The onus is on the asker to boil it down so that someone can answer quickly.

Comment: theMayer- I updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

I would go about this a bit differently, and instead create a `FormArray` of your ages. Then those are just toggled `false` or `true`. On submit, we filter those checkboxes that are `true`:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  getAPIData().subscribe((...) => {
    // is ages coming from api? Then change accordingly!
    const ages = this.ages.map(x => this.fb.control(false))
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      userage: this.fb.array(ages),
    });
  })
}

// create a getter for easier access (not necessary)
get ageArr() {
  return this.myForm.get('userage') as FormArray;
}

checkAll() {
  this.ageArr.controls.map(value => value.setValue(true))
}

deselectAll() {
  this.ageArr.controls.map(value => value.setValue(false))
}
```

And in template we iterate the formarray instead of the `ages` array. Also remember to put `type="button"` on your select all and deselect all buttons, since otherwise they will be considered as `type="submit"` by default.

If this is coming async, your better set a `*ngIf` on the form tag

```html
<form *ngIf="myForm">
 <!-- -->
   <div formArrayName="userage" *ngFor="let age of ageArr.controls; let i = index">
     <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i"> {{ages[i].name}}
   </div>
</form>
```

Then as mentioned earlier, just filter the `true` values on submit:

```ts
onSubmit() {
  const chosenAges = this.ageArr.value
    .map((age, i) => age ? this.ages[i].name : null)
    .filter(age => age !== null);
  console.log(chosenAges);
}
```

Your **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7r2ul?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: In actual scenario I'm getting data from API. So I need to call getAPIData() method in ngOnInit. Then how can I push the values?

Comment: do it inside the subscribe callback, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, we need to get out of event-driven mode and start thinking about data-driven mode, which is the strength of Angular.

You do not want to wrap this in a `<Form>`. All that does is cause a post-back when you're trying to submit, which goes against the point of Angular being a single-page app (note that there are cases when a `<Form>` is appropriate, namely validation, and only if the submit event is intercepted).

I got rid of your form group and tweaked your HTML template to follow the methodology employed by Angular data binding. I added the use of `[(ngModel)]` to bind your checkbox to your underlying data, and I added an `isChecked` property to the data model.

See [the Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7hwrt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

**Template Changes**:

`<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="data.isChecked" />`

**Main Code Changes**:

```
  checkAll(){
    this.ages.forEach(o => o.isChecked = true);
  }
  uncheckAll(){
    this.ages.forEach(o => o.isChecked = false);
  }
```

**Your Data:**

```
  ages = [
  { ageID: 100, name: "0 -10 years", isChecked: false },
  { ageID: 200, name: "10 -20 years", isChecked: false },
  { ageID: 300, name: "30 -40 years", isChecked: false },
  { ageID: 400, name: "40 -50 years", isChecked: false }];

  languages = [
    { langID: 1, name: "English", isChecked: false },
    { langID: 2, name: "Tamil", isChecked: false },
    { langID: 3, name: "Hindi", isChecked: false },
    { langID: 4, name: "French", isChecked: false }];
```

Comment: In my scenario I have to use Reactive forms